# How to perform Path.Data.Transform in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a path object in the code behind and scaling it. PFB the code.

```
path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
path.StrokeThickness = 1;`
path.Data.Transform = new ScaleTransform(0.5,0.5);
```

How to do the same in XAML?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `Transform` property of the Geometry in a Path's `Data` in XAML would look like shown below. In contrast to the Path's `RenderTransform`, the `Geometry.Transform` property only transform the geometry, but not any visual aspects like e.g. the StrokeThickness.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                M 0,10 L10,0 20,10 10,20Z
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

You can write something like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" x:Key="testTransform" />
</Window.Resources>

<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Transform="{StaticResource testTransform}">
            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,50">
                <LineSegment Point="200,70" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do this way please, <Path RenderTranform=" ">

Comment: This is not what was asked for. The question was about the Transform property of the Geometry in a Path's Data. The answer is about a Path's RenderTransform. The latter visually transforms the Path (including e.g. its StrokeThickness), while the former only transforms the geometry.